# Return type of sync/async method based on class property

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, typescript-generics

My class has two methods: `register()` and `process()`. The `register()` method is used to associate a function to the class, this function can be synchronous or asynchronous. The process method on the other hand is used to run the registered function over an array of items.

The return type of the `process()` method should be of `Promise<SomeType[]>` if the registered function is async, otherwise simply `SomeType[]`.

Below is the implementation that I was able to come up with, as you can see I am defining two type `AnyFunction` and `AnyAsyncFunction` to represent synchronous & asynchronous handler functions, and then I'm using these types in the generic `Func` type of the class.

My reasoning is that doing so would allow me to pass that `Func` generic to the return type of the `process()` method (`ProcessReturn<Func>`) and have it return a type or that type wrapped by a `Promise` depending on whether `Func` extends `AnyFunction` or `AnyAsyncFunction`.

```
// Existing types (simplified)
type EventSourceDataClassTypes = "event" | "eventBatch" | "eventBatchError";

type ResultType = unknown;
type SuccessResponse = ["success", ResultType, EventSourceDataClassTypes];
type FailureResponse = ["fail", string, EventSourceDataClassTypes];

// New types
type AnyFunction = (...args: Array<any>) => any;
type AnyAsyncFunction = (...args: Array<any>) => Promise<any>;

// If the handler is sync, it returns an array of SuccessResponse | FailureResponse
// If the handler is async, it returns a Promise of an array of SuccessResponse | FailureResponse
type ProcessReturn<Func extends AnyFunction | AnyAsyncFunction> =
  Func extends AnyAsyncFunction
    ? Promise<(SuccessResponse | FailureResponse)[]>
    : (SuccessResponse | FailureResponse)[];

class Batch<Func extends AnyFunction | AnyAsyncFunction> {
  private handler?: Func;
  private records: Array<string> = [];

  public constructor(records: Array<string> = []) {
    this.records = records;
  }

  public register(handler: Func): void {
    this.handler = handler;
  }

  public process(): ProcessReturn<Func> {
    if (!this.handler) {
      throw new Error("No handler registered");
    }

    const processedRecords: (SuccessResponse | FailureResponse)[] = [];
    for (const record of this.records) {
      processedRecords.push(this.handler(record));
    }

    if (this.handler.constructor.name === "AsyncFunction") {
      return Promise.all(processedRecords) as ProcessReturn<Func>;
    } else {
      return processedRecords as ProcessReturn<Func>;
    }
  }
}
```

When using the class above like below, the implementation works at runtime, however TypeScript complains about the return type.

```
const main = async () => {
  const batch = new Batch(["record1", "record2", "record3"]);

  const mySyncHandler = (
    record: unknown
  ): SuccessResponse | FailureResponse => {
    if (record === "record2") {
      return ["fail", "Hello world", "event"];
    } else {
      return ["success", "Hello world", "event"];
    }
  };

  const myAsyncHandler = async (
    record: unknown
  ): Promise<SuccessResponse | FailureResponse> => {
    // Test async/await
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
    if (record === "record2") {
      return ["fail", "Hello world", "event"];
    } else {
      return ["success", "Hello world", "event"];
    }
  };

  let result: (SuccessResponse | FailureResponse)[];

  // Register a sync handler
  batch.register(mySyncHandler);
  // Run the handler
  result = batch.process(); // <- TS thinks return type here is a Promise<...>
  console.log(result); // Should print result

  // Register an async handler
  batch.register(myAsyncHandler);
  // Run the handler
  result = await batch.process();
  console.log(result); // Should print result (if not awaited, it would print an array of pending Promise)
};

main();
```

Am I missing something? Does anyone have an idea of how to make this work? Is the approach completely wrong?

[Here's the same code as above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFEA8EsGcBdoDsDmp4E8AOBTWoAKWaAWywBtoAzaHAEwEoAoTXCANxyXgGUB7AK4AnAMY4AIgEN4kgMLlJsWABVseUAF5QAIhydu20AB8dervABC0kQAtDJ3fsvWb4IUL5DtAbiYs1oABKeALk8KpsWgJIANZIfADuSL6sOKA8AiJiSsGwWHxIsGlaANrasJnZsNoANEEhYRE4deBO-MJiUjLyiipqsAC6KQEAYpLQ5MI4ufmFxaBlVOPktaAIQsgoLW2CohLScgpKTYO+TCCgAHI4Cej9-mwAgkgYI9EiiAWahAB0f5JCFCwABcoEe7kkGAAPJIXgA+BiaOGgWEYYZPF6PWAYJAiN64z5Ib4EP4-AFA0HgoSQmHwxEaZEABQ8JDgOFpGDhZwuAEkqOgbGkbLC6OQcEJQHA1jiRHVoPBQEIcPBhIUUUSAdSMKA+PyMlk8LAZgUisZQGMJlNjXNzmA+QKhSKxRKpYoZXKFUqVUI1ZJQMy+KzTbr1SiIdqQ-qqtbTSYLZMlTGcA80gHo8rVVD8SJQDhIPAuHR8M9Xu9CWaS1iZdnCciNExQOb3rn84Xi5jsbia9ACg3G6AAPz+llsqEEKOGpNm+NWvCzIoMEoDOF9xug8eVSdzk1pOPLWd5HeLoZ+ERHfBWeC2LPNvMFpBFsEvbtfEyVzt4ss9pDIgDefawDZ2GkR0H2dAdQWzXxG0A6BgILRUcBETwi0pcMoXWTY6wWE8AIEAAjSgc2Qwp4CETJ4E8AglWQoRULBdDMNQbCl0Rf9+wFOAfholD8C0Hi6NgaDQAAXz8GCCKIxCUDgAshAIYUwPFSD3gYUF2D4aA6FAdj+3gGwuMU0VxW+IznWEsS8MI6Ac0AvgqgINTh3srdvSQG9cT-VdJX5AgAEJ9MMp1xTY7zG30jxbiQG4IHcKjtEuPhQDMkylRkhBxXobQGGExtLI4kiEFAOyqnoYJaPojcDRybc5mnfdE1qhcl2+JdctAKhPEIQrPSQlCdX5QLYG4vrBNCjiYI8Uq6HK3ifiwARYBsAghp+FL5IExgcu8-L+2oQhVvWn4evIj5PB+JBJBIYoNC0bQqy7L8CmynSwsQtznKDHAyXIcgCBKw0ytGotEUUZz0zcjyRC5Hbc3IU1dI4r1VWKqbAZm4H8DBtNXMzbMYY4sS8qYSyetAEhxiJLQ3VxQh6S8xsyfwlxvmi25L1sAgyk2gBGVZtE2gAmfnNoAZm0AZtr7MmSAwHgZQACWCiUtAIbzNtBaI4kSJA+ycicasPOq90tRqjdNBlXo4-bqOBzRbp0IWXsR-tkZ9BZtCWCZ+YVnBfqShJPHIOh+bMAwT0JuGEbet2iTKCpquqOptF9-3QEDoRg9DpwJfaonRLORmTQVWWHpEJWlJVlEP0IdXgc12J4iSPXQQDL6oQNo0mt3c0Gumbu6wZ-sLmUPAFRpkRgEkBJxngbzp9n0A2c+tkCFt2A+HITh6bWZVlFIHBBHgdfN84OoeYABgvhhtut3zNvtu6nfGibY49r2VmT1PyADoOQ+TsO8Bc6wz9tHCa70Ubx03EoH2fsf7pz-tncwwDCZ9hEoXUAYpeoVDCOuTuU4TYJn7ubHAx4MEXGCOlOSKJpS03Wn2ZmV4bAjSoeKAgst5a4grsZIQt9QAUOiA6ZKys+xKhwQqLQjDbDzTRkoRywlCqb2+j-FA69QjwByvwsAzJkDwHwCnOBv9M4h3Elo+orCJSwmrjKYRlcGEuBYbJNhpcPzcOdHwgRRJ9KgR4aIhoEiUQz3lKAKRzCAZyL4YosUPwVFqLCJoi4OjuD6O-kYrOhB9rxHHkEgsdAPQINCNpWC3AaG4AfJsFeC4SZnApsgeRTAgA) in a TS playground if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type ProcessReturn<Func extends AnyFunction | AnyAsyncFunction> =
  Func extends AnyAsyncFunction
    ? Promise<(SuccessResponse | FailureResponse)[]>
    : (SuccessResponse | FailureResponse)[];
```

This type is not a function, it will be evaluated just one time, at compile time. The result of this type is possibly a promise, so indeed TypeScript will deny your code as the output can be a promise (cannot guess at compile time).

Comment: I see, any hint on how it would look like if it was a function? Do you mean a type guard?

Comment: You are overusing types, there is no guarantee to do runtime type checks without additional tools like io-ts, reflect-metadata and such. I would just add another function register named 'registerAsyncHandler' and keep 2 lists of handlers in your class, and then just do the handling thing.